# how to use auto_increment in fuelphp to create table

Tags: fuelphp

I write a fileds like this

```
$fileds = array(
    'id' => array('type' => 'integer','AUTO_INCREMENT'=>true),
    'user' => array('type' => 'text'),
    'time' => array('type' => 'integer')
);
```

When I run this`DBUtil::create_table($table, $fileds);`
it turn wrong,

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error' in /home/yangjun/phpenv/public_html/cmanage/fuel/core/classes/database/pdo/connection.php:239
```

What is wrong ?
ihave rewrite a new test,and add primary key,but doesn't work,i read the document in fuelphp,no idea~

```
<?php

/**
 * @group test
 */
class Test extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUPBeforeClass()
    {
        DBUtil::set_connection('request');
        $table = 'test';
        $fileds = array(
            '_id' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'auto_increment' => true),
            '_name' => array('type' => 'test'),
            '_data' => array('type' => 'test')
        );
        $primary_keys = array('_id');

        DBUtil::create_table($table, $fileds, $primary_keys);
    }

    public function test_add_keycode_request()
    {
        $RequestData = array(
            '_id' => '',
            '_name' => 'hhh',
            '_data' => 'ggg');
        $RequestData1 = array(
            '_id' => '',
            '_name' => 'hhhh',
            '_data' => 'gggg');
        self::add_request($RequestData);
        self::add_request($RequestData1);
        Cli::write(__METHOD__ . "   √ \n", 'green');
    }

    public static function add_request($RequestData)
    {
        try {
            $result = \DB::insert('test')
                ->set($RequestData)
                ->execute('request');
        } catch (\Database_Exception $e) {
            \Log::error('DB access Error' . $e);
            throw $e;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

error log,this is whole error log,synatax error?

```
Test
1.exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error' in /home//phpenv/public_html/fuel/core/classes/database/pdo/connection.php:239
2.Next exception 'Fuel\Core\Database_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error with query: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "test" (
"_id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
"_name" test NOT NULL,
"_data" test NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY "_id" ("_id"));"' in /home/yangjun/phpenv/public_html/fuel/core/classes/database/pdo/connection.php:272
```

Comment: Have you set `id` as the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Seems is missing the `constraint` param on columns field (i don't know also if `int` or `integer` type field).

Try this:

```
$fileds = array(
'id' => array('constraint' => 11,'type' => 'integer','AUTO_INCREMENT'=>true),
'user' => array('type' => 'text'),
'time' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'integer'))
}
```

**UPDATE**

Need to specify the primary key also:

```
DBUtil::create_table($table, $fileds, array('id'));
```

More info in the doc [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/dbutil.html)

Hope this help

Comment: thanks,i had try your method.but seem doesn't work,i updata the log,do you have any idea?